# Circe : Serialize case class body fields to JSON

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have a case class with some `val` (which is not a constructor param). How can I get those fields also in the generated json ?

I was using `Json4s` before, and used `FieldSerializer` which did this trick. But unable to get this with Circe.

What I want is to define all the required fields in a trait, sometimes, the field may be a part of the case class. But there are cases, where it doesn't make sense to keep them as part of case class, but still needed in the json.
Please note the difference between `EntityWithBodyParams` and `AnotherEntity` below.

Here is my sample case class.

```
trait NamedEntity {
    def name:String
}

case class EntityWithBodyParams(id:Long) extends NamedEntity {
  override val name:String = "Name"
}

case class AnotherEntity(id:Long, name:String) extends NamedEntity
```

Response after asJson

```
{
  "id" : 100
}
```

But my expectation is :

```
{
  "id" : 100,
  "name":"Name"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `Encoder`.

```
import io.circe.{Encoder, Json}

case class EntityWithBodyParams(id: Long) {
  val name: String = "Name"
}

implicit val encoder: Encoder[EntityWithBodyParams] = new 
Encoder[EntityWithBodyParams] {
  override def apply(entity: EntityWithBodyParams): Json = Json.obj(
    "id"   -> Json.fromLong(entity.id),
    "name" -> Json.fromString(entity.name)
  )
}
```

Reason for this behavior is fact that circe auto encoder uses only `product` fields of case class. More info you can find here https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Comment: Does that mean that for each case class, I need to add this encoder ? Isn't there any other way? I can have the body fields in a separate trait and extend with all the case classes and override the value. But otherthan that, adding the custom encoder for all case class is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your case class like this instead.

```
case class EntityWithBodyParams(id:Long, val name:String = "Name")
```